# Button function not working when adding css in react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

i have the button and used for trigger some other pages. i just try with adding css using styled components, the styles are applied perfectly but the function is not working. which means function is working if i remove the styles. if i add the styles the page not called function not working.

and suggest me how to add makestyles here!

here i showed my button component here.

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Popover from "@material-ui/core/Popover";
import Menu from "@material-ui/core/Menu";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";
import ComponentType from "../ComponentType";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

// StyledButton

const TriggerButton = styled.button`
cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: #664e96;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  &:hover {
    background: #664e96;
    color: #fff;
  }
`;

export default class AddTriggerButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false,
      props: props,
    };
  }

  render() {
    
    return (
      <div>
        <TriggerButton
          component={Link}
          to={{
            pathname: "/_triggers/create",
            data: { eid: this.state.props.record.id },
          }}
          startIcon={<AddIcon />}
        >
          New Trigger
          </TriggerButton>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect a `<button>` component to support a `component` prop?

Comment: i need to trigger some other pages so i used like this. is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to use the MUI button, change its component to a styled one, and use it to navigate with react router, this is one approach:

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Popover from "@material-ui/core/Popover";
import Menu from "@material-ui/core/Menu";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";
import ComponentType from "../ComponentType";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

// StyledButton
const StyledLink = styled(Link)`
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: #664e96;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  &:hover {
    background: #664e96;
    color: #fff;
  }
`;

const TriggerButton = ({ children, to, ...props }) => {
  const CustomLink = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      React.forwardRef((linkProps, ref) => (
        <StyledLink ref={ref} to={to} {...linkProps} />
      )),
    [to]
  );

  return (
    <Button {...props} component={CustomLink}>
      {children}
    </Button>
  );
};

export default class AddTriggerButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false,
      props: props
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TriggerButton
          to={{
            pathname: "/_triggers/create",
            data: { eid: this.state.props.record.id }
          }}
          startIcon={<AddIcon />}
        >
          New Trigger
        </TriggerButton>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Example https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-parm-fntxg

There are better ways to reuse this, but that's a way to composite them together, take a look at https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/